# an additional e2open:Item element appears in the output

Tags: xslt

An extra `<e2open:Item>` is appearing in the code. kindly validate the code and suggest me a solution, thanks in advance

*************************************** My Input ***********************************************

```
<e2open:ItemMessage xmlns:e2open="http://www.e2open.com/E2openMCM">
<e2open:Item itemIdentifier="30N20" description="SRV,OS,WINBLUE,QFE,KB3037317" revision="X00-00"
           lifeCycleCode="X Revision" itemPartType="Service Install" itemClassification="Service Install"
           proprietaryProductFamily="Inspiron" makeBuy="XCom Design" revisionReleaseDate="2015-05-13T05:54:49+00:00"
           businessEntity="95" businessEntityType="ENTERPRISE" dataSource="XCom" operationCode="A">

</e2open:Item>
<e2open:Item itemIdentifier="J7C27" description="SRV,OS,WINBLUE,QFE,KB3022289" revision="X00-00"
           lifeCycleCode="X Revision" itemPartType="Service Install" itemClassification="Service Install"
           proprietaryProductFamily="Inspiron" makeBuy="XCom Design" revisionReleaseDate="2015-05-13T05:54:49+00:00"
           businessEntity="95" businessEntityType="ENTERPRISE" dataSource="XCom" operationCode="A">

</e2open:Item>
</e2open:ItemMessage>
```

*************************************** My XSLT ***********************************************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:e2open="http://www.e2open.com/E2openMCM" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="e2open:ItemMessage">
<xsl:element name="e2open:ItemMessage" xmlns="http://www.e2open.com/E2openMCM">
<xsl:attribute name="headerVersion">1.0</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="fromID">XCom</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="toID">E2OPEN</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="messageType">Item</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="messageVersion">MCM1.0</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="messageCount">1</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="messageIndex"><xsl:value-of select="@messageIndex"/>      </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="e2open:Item">
 <xsl:if test="@itemClassification!='Software Bundle'">
 <xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unable to paste the output here .. so Please run the xslt with the given input. Kindly note that the output comes with an additional e2open:Item element in the beginning of each e2open:Item itemIdentifier

Comment: Your supposed **output** is not as what you claim if your input is tested on your XSLT.

Comment: Hi Joel .. i have rephrased the issue .. could you please check it, i am unable to paste the output in the text box

Comment: See this link (http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQP/1)

Comment: seems the link is broken :(